# Extract words in Bold, any solution?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I intend to extract only the words that are in bold, for a column. Does anyone have a VBA code to recognize bold text? I need him to recognize the posting in bold and extract only the highlighted words
[image]

Comment: I dont know, But I think would be easier if you can find a pattern in the text (say extract all the words with alphabetic characters and leave numbers after)

Comment: You will need to loop each cell then loop each character and test if bold.

Comment: see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters

Comment: DDS, It would not be possible, because there is text and number among them

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Stack Overflow post
[Excel extract bold Words in text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405782/165358)
contains the following VBA function to extract bold text, character by
character:

```
 Public Function findAllBold(ByVal rngText As Range) As String
    Dim theCell As Range
    Set theCell = rngText.Cells(1, 1)

    For i = 1 To Len(theCell.Value)       
        If theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then          
            If theCell.Characters(i + 1, 1).Text = " " Then
                theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text & ", "
                Else
                theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
            End If
            Results = Results & theChar
        End If
   Next i
   findAllBold = Results
End Function
```

This function adds commas between the found words.
To omit this, delete this text : `& ", "`.
The entire `if` command can in this case be shortened to one line:
`theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text`.

Use this function to extract the bold text from the first cell, then extend the
formula to the following lines:

[image]

Comment: harrymc, This is what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @ElienayJunior - A fun exercise would be to try and add an argument to the function that allows the user to define the delimiter.